# Azure VM has four 1 TB data disks, but Windows Server recognizes only two 500 GB disk

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, azure-storage

What could explain the following scenario?

- VM of size "Standard D2 v2" (ARM deployment)
- Four 1023 GiB data disks of type Standard_LRS Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter guest OS Disk
- Management shows only two data disks of 500.87 GB each
- Rescan disks changes nothing

One of the two recognized 500.81 GB disks is out of space and I need to expand it. When I deallocated the VM to make the change, I saw the disk was already twice what Windows is recognizing.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of teh Azure disk configuration?

Comment: Could you please show screenshots of Azure disk configuration and windows disk management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason these disks were not showing up as expected in Windows Disk Management is because Storage Spaces was in use. After expanding the disks there I was able to see the additional space in Disk Management and expand the volumes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, maybe we should check Azure disk configuration via Azure portal, make sure four data disks attached to this VM, if not, we should attach them.

After four data disks attached to that VM, we should initialize(expand) data disk in **windows disk management**, we can follow this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/attach-disk#option-1-attach-and-initialize-a-new-disk) to do it.